# How to back to previous Tab layout specific tab(Fragment) from another activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

[image]

First of all, I have search through on StackOverflow and read some of the related posts but it doesn't really fix my problem. From the screenshot, you can see that I have added some coding to the AndroidManifest which will add an "Arrow" on the top left-hand corner - it serves as a back button.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".MainStory"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
```

**On my MainActivity Tab 3 Fragment**

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),MainStory.class);
        startActivity(intent);

}
```

So from the screenshot, **I am at Tab 3 with a ListFragment**. After clicking either one of the item, it will **go to MainStory activity**. If i click the device "Back button" , it will go back to MainActivity Tab 3(this is what I want).

However, **When i click the "Arrow" it will return to MainActivity Tab 1 but not Tab 3 of MainActivity.**

So my question is how to go back to **Tab 3 Fragment** just like the device "back button" when clicked on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do something like this on the toolbar:

```
protected Toolbar setUpToolBar(String title) {
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
if (actionBar != null) {
  actionBar.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color=\"#ffffff\">" + title + "</font>"));
  actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
  actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
} else {
  AMLog.d("Action bar is null");
}
if (toolbar != null) {
  toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      onBackPressed();
    }
  });
}
return toolbar;
```

}

Comment: This code is doing same as you are doing  in onBackPressed. toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener takes the click of  <- arrow button.
First check if this solve your problem or not.
Put this code in MainStory where you creating toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Do this, it worked for me:

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    finish(); // Returns you to the last tab that you were before navigating
    return false; // Cancels out the default action that takes you back to the 1st tab
}
```

Hope it helps,

Cheers